# Combining prefetch_related() and only() in a Django QuerySet

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to execute the following query:

```
ParentModel.objects.prefetch_related('child_model').only('parent_attribute', 'childs__child_atrtibute').all()
```

It doesn't seem to work. Django throws the following exception:

```
'RelatedObject' object has no attribute 'rel'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/…path_to_my_app…/models.py", line 123, in _nested_commit_on_success
    return commit_on_success(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 223, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/…path_to_my_app…/views.py", line 1047, in my_veiw_function
    MyParentModel.objects.prefetch_related('my_child_model').only('my_parent_attribute', 'my_child_model__my_child_attribute').all():
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 102, in __iter__
    len(self)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 90, in __len__
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in iterator
    only_load = self.query.get_loaded_field_names()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1888, in get_loaded_field_names
    self.deferred_to_data(collection, self.get_loaded_field_names_cb)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 591, in deferred_to_data
    cur_model = source.rel.to
AttributeError: 'RelatedObject' object has no attribute 'rel'
```

If I remove the `childs__child_atrtibute` argument from the `only()` method, everything works as expected, but my query returns unnecessary data.

Django manual says we can combine `only()` and `defer()` with fields from `select_related()`.

But is there a way to use `only()` with fields from `prefetch_related()`?

I tried to rather use `ChildModel.objects.only('child_attribute').all()` later in my code, but it just generates tons of queries instead of using cached results from `prefetch_related()`.

I am using Django 1.5.

Comment: Did you found any solution for this question ?

Comment: This is not currently possible. But there is a ticket on djangoproject.com that will allow to do this in future: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17001

Answer (score 2):

I know i am probably late here and not according to the requirements of the question (Django 1.5), but in case if this helps any one...

As of Django 1.8, using [Prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) objects, this can probably be achieved as follows:

```
ParentModel.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'child_model',
        queryset=ChildModel.objects.all().only(
             'parent_attribute', 'childs__child_atrtibute'
        )
    )
)
```